# Expectation of exponential of normal random variable

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution

I'm trying to work out the expectation of $E[e^{uX^{2}}]$ where $X \sim N(0, 1)$. Now, from my understanding:
$$
E[e^{uX^{2}}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}(1 - 2u)} = e^{(1 - 2u)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}} = e^{1 - 2u}
$$
However, my teacher found the result that $E[e^{uX^{2}}] = (1 - 2u)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. However, I'm not sure how he obtained that result

Answer (score 2):

Your step after the integral
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}(1 - 2u)}\,dx\tag1$$
is incorrect. To evaluate (1) you should make the change of variables $t:=x\sqrt{1-2u}$. Then $dt=dx\sqrt{1-2u}$ and
(1) becomes
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac12t^2}\frac1{\sqrt{1-2u}}\,dt=
\frac1{\sqrt{1-2u}}\underbrace{\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac12t^2}\,dt}_1.
$$

Comment: okay, but I don't understand why my step is wrong, since the exponential of $(1 - 2u)$ doesn't depend on x,  is it not possible for me to take it out the integral?

Comment: @electro7912 In your step you are using $e^{ab} = e^a e^b$, which is illegal. True is: $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$